# Has been fixed to "be held" / "take place"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

In a *leave application* to school headmaster which is better:

> Dear Sir,
>                    My elder sister's marriage has been fixed to **be held** / **take place** on 18th of February.......

Which, in a native speaker's opinion, is the best to use for a *high school student*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Take place" sounds better to this Br.Eng speaker.

Comment: @stevekeiretsu could you please give me a sample letter?